# Social Studio Radian6 Get Tweets Data

Tags: twitter, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I want to fetch various social media accounts data through Radian6 API (particularly Twitter).

I have my defined url as:

```
headers = {"access_token": key}

url = 'https://api.socialstudio.radian6.com/v3/posts?topics=1234567&startDate=' 
+ startDate + '&endDate=' + endDate

resp = session.get(url, headers=headers)

Json = json.loads(resp.content)
```

where duration between start and end date covers all my records in the current day.

In the JSON that I am getting, for the data fetched from sources other than twitter, I am getting the content text but for tweets, I am not getting any data.

Do I need to add special privileges to my account or is getting tweets data not possible through the API, or is it I am doing something wrong. Need help in this.

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow.  Can you just change the variable name `Json` to something else, I am not sure if you are using python or some other language, but `Json` word can interfere in a language which is case-insensitive.

Comment: yeah i am using python. I changed that word. But the problem still persists.